# Why is the execution context of ES6 IIFEs and ES5 IIFEs different?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, iife, executioncontext

The title about sums up the question - this is the code example:

```
!function() {
    console.log(this); // global object
}();

(function() {
    console.log(this); // global object
})();

() => {
    console.log(this); // {}
}();

var x = (function() {
    console.log(this); // global object
})();
```

What is happening behind the scenes wrt to the arrow function? If I wanted that scope in ES5, so far as I know, I would have to bind the execution to an empty object like so:

```
!function() {
    console.log(this); // global object
}.bind({})();
```

Comment: Are you running this in Node or another CommonJS system?

Comment: what is the lexical scope of arrow function that you used?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this

Comment: Example 4 with the `var x` is no different than example 2.

Comment: @naomik - thanks. I see x is just undefined

Comment: @ZachSmith that's because the function doesn't return anything.

Comment: ah. then they are not the same. since you are storing a variable with example 4, but not with example 2 (if there is a return)

Comment: @ZachSmith my point was more about the IIFE being identical. Variable assignment is irrelevant to the topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's nothing to do with ES5 or ES6, arrow functions always get the enclosing function's context. Function invocation without using `'use strict';` is always get the global object as context (window in the browser for example), when used, the context is `undefined` by default.

This is a very good article explaining the topic:

https://dmitripavlutin.com/gentle-explanation-of-this-in-javascript/